# Sum of numbers contained in strings

Tags: c, arrays, string

Given a text file, for example:

```
cdcd dcdaqw cdcd KKAN 89 bxb hqhq1bhA
100uuz
cnkx


 n jk xjx100mc
...
.+1+
```

I want to find the sum of all  the numbers contained in the various strings:
In the given example, I want to sum 89 100 1 100 1.

I made many attempts at this(IE, fscanf of each string and trying to save the int values in an array), but they all failed.

Comment: Show what have you tried ?

Comment: Don't do this in C. Can you choose e.g. Python?

Comment: Dear Sir/Madam, I can have my team of expert software developers write this program for you. Please forward your standard contract along with rates you are willing to pay and we will negotiate the project.

Comment: "I made many attempts at this but they all failed." Without you posting that code, how could we point out where you went wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this is fairly straightforward. At every position in the file we ask "is there a number here?". If there is, print it out. If there isn't try starting at the next character.

Based on how we understand `fscanf()` works, we'll test each character at most twice.

#### Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main() {
    FILE * fd = fopen("in.txt", "r");

    while (true) {
        unsigned number;
        int rc = fscanf(fd, "%u", &number);
        if (rc == EOF)
            break;
        else if (rc == 0)
            fseek(fd, 1, SEEK_CUR);
        else if (rc == 1)
            printf("%u\n", number);
    }
}
```

#### Input File

```
cdcd dcdaqw cdcd KKAN 89 bxb hqhq1bhA
100uuz
cnkx

 n jk xjx100mc
...
.+1+
```

#### Output

```
89
1
100
100
1
```

#### Next steps

It should be fairly obvious how to extend this to report the sum, instead of the numbers themselves.

Comment: This handles it quite well. Only other recommendations I could have are

1. RegEx (the integer RegEx should be pretty simple)
2. Use a different language (Java, C++) with better IO support (Java Scanners, C++ std:>> operators)

Answer (score 0):

You could be using [strtol](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/)

You have an example at the bottom of the page which does pretty much what you want. You're only going to need to manually skip the non-digit characters